# Azur AD B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have added a user flow, and want to overwrite that with my own custom policy as per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9qN6QqnxQ8) or [this article](https://blog.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7751).

The only issue is that I am using `openId connect` and this is for `local account` only, anyone knows how to change the xml to `openId Connect` instead?

There are samples for social accounts but I get errors about Facebook oatuh.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard set of custom policies comes with Facebook included as an example of federation.

Just comment out all the Facebook references or else create a dummy FacebookSecret key.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did comment it out in base and extension xmls, but it still complains. Also for openid connect do I use social? Can you please provide an sample or the 3 files

Comment: You need to use social if you want to use an external IDP with OIDC. For local-only you don't need social. Look at the local sample in the starter pack.

Comment: got that working with social. my last question is how would page layout customization work? I assume I would call these custom policy work flows from my UI right?

Comment: Look at the MSAL samples to see how to call it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples